# "Cannot find declaration to go to" error on a simple HTML linking to a controller

Tags: java, spring, api, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf along with Spring Boot to create a CRUD API.

The code below is regarding the creation of a table on a HTML file :

```
        <tr th:each="titulo : ${titulos}" th:value="titulo">
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${titulo.codigo}">1</td>
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${titulo.descricao}"></td>
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${titulo.dataVencimento}"></td>
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${titulo.valor}"></td>
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${titulo.status.descricao}"></td>
            <td class="text-center">
```

The following is code from the controller class regarding the attribute "titulos" declared above :

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView pesquisar() {
    List<Titulo> todosTitulos = titulosRepository.findAll();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("titulos", todosTitulos);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting the following error :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [titulos], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Before someone points it out, I'm using `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"` inside the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to identify the viewName when creating my modelAndView attribute :

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("PesquisaTitulos");
```